# how to search object by hash key in a array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an objects in a array,

If now I want to pickup the 2nd object `{'name':'automating','letter':'Automating', 'num':1, 'color':'red' }`

with the key `name` and value equals to  `automating`.

How could I pick up it from the array?

```
Ember.A([
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'manual','letter':'Manual', 'num':1 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'automating','letter':'Automating', 'num':1, 'color':'red' }),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'coverage','letter':'Coverage', 'num':1,'color':'yellow' }),      
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'round','letter':'Rounds', 'num':1}),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'roi_round','letter':'Round', 'num':1 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'roi_year','letter':'Year', 'num':1}),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'roi_round_coverage','letter':'Round"', 'num':1 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'name':'roi_year_with_coverage','letter':'Year"', 'num':10 }),
    ]);
```

Comment: try `filter` of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter`, e.g.

```
function findObj(arr, selector) {
    return arr.filter( function (a) {
        return a[selector.key] == selector.value;
    });
}
```

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/hqLh8tbv/) on how to apply this

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `Array.filter`

Comment: [Ember.Array has a find method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_find) (and also findBy)